# Tomcat error when using Tomcat-Deployer on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

When i deploy my application via a WAR file on my tomcat server, the application runs perfectly, However when i use [Tomcat Deployer plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tomcatdeployer/) which deploys the directories instead of a WAR file i get the following error.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Wrapper cannot find servlet class org.code.KathyServlet      or a class it depends on
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.code.KathyServlet
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Proto         col.java:602)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I have tried giving it a class-path in the MANIFEST file but it did not make a difference.

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web- app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>HFJse</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>KathyServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.code.KathyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>KathyServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: First check if the class is correcty deployed. See also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706140/eclipse-keeps-running-my-old-web-application/706165#706165

Comment: This is on a remote server btw on Centos, the application works fine on localhost Tomcat via eclipse.

Comment: show us the web.xml file

Comment: i have now included it in the main question.

Comment: check if your KathyServlet.class file is placed in `/WEB-INF/classes/org/code/KathyServlet.class`

Comment: Yes the necessary class files are in the location mentioned.

Comment: and also check if in your kathyServlet.java code `package org.code` is written or not

Comment: Yes package org.code is written