# Web-xml <servlet-class> to a servlet under default package Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a question regarding a servlet placed in a default package.

Under web-xml, I am supposed to map the servlets.

What do I key in under  in eclipse if the servlet is in the default package?

I understand that all classes should be put in proper packages but the above is a practice question.

Could anyone let me know as I cant seem to find the answer on the internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your Servlets class is "HelloTest" and name is hello, Then Web.xml entry should be

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>HelloTest</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Also Please check [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706140/eclipse-keeps-running-my-old-web-application/706165#706165) also

Answer (score 0):

The entry in the web.xml should be like this,

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>Test</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

You can follow this article for further details http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html